# filesize from a String

Tags: php, string, blob, filesize

how can i get the "filesize" from a string in php?

I put the string in a mysql database as a blob and i need to store the size of the blob. My solution was to create a temp file and put the string into the temp file. now i can get the filesize from the "string". but that solution is not good...

greetings

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It depends.  If you have [mbstring function overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) enabled, the only call that will work will be `mb_strlen($string, '8bit');`.  If it's not enabled, `strlen($string)` will work fine as well.

So, you can handle both cases like this:

```
if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
    $size = mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
} else {
    $size = strlen($string);
}
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?  What's wrong or incomplete about this answer?

Comment: -1 Why use `mb_strlen()` at all when `strlen()` will always work? See my answer below.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith: because, as I indicated in the answer, it won't always work. If [`mb_string.overload`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php) is on, `strlen()` will return the number of UTF-8 characters, not the number of bytes. So no, this is required...

Comment: In 7.2 this was deprecated, in version 8 it was removed. You should _NOT_ use this method.

Comment: @Mike what exactly are you talking about? What was removed in PHP 8? strlen()? mb_strlen()? function_exists()? All these methods are still in use, and were NOT deprecated neither removed yet.

Comment: @montie He's probably referring to `mb_string,overload`

Answer (score 7):

SELECT length(field) FROM table

From the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length):

> LENGTH(str)
>
> Returns the length of the string str,
>   measured in bytes. A multi-byte
>   character counts as multiple bytes.
>   This means that for a string
>   containing five two-byte characters,
>   LENGTH() returns 10, whereas
>   CHAR_LENGTH() returns 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
strlen()
```

before putting it into mysql, or in SQL:

```
LENGTH()
```

Notice that lenght can be various depending on character set. If you want to have real length in bytes use strlen(), if you want to have character count use mb_strlen() (if you have utf-8 encoding for example)

Comment: strlen() can be flawed, see @ircmaxell's answer

Answer (score 0):

If all you are storing is the string, then the size should be the length of your string times the number of bytes in the charset. So for Unicode that would be 2*strlen($string).

Comment: AFAIK only special chars have double size. So letter 'a' will have one byte, but letters like ó,ł,ż,ć,ś etc. will be 2-bytes long

Comment: Yup, UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding, characters can be between 1 and 4 bytes long. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

`strlen($string)` is the best example for viewing the size(MB) of a string

strlen() doesnt actually return the number of elements in a string, but the number of bytes in it

example:
`echo(strlen('a■'));` will return 4, because the black square character is made of 3 bytes, and the 'a' character is made of one.

Comment: It's great that you're providing an example to better explain, but otherwise your answer looks the same as the accepted one from 2010. If you agree, maybe you could edit that answer to add your example and delete this one?

Answer (score -3):

use [mb_strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) as then you can tell it what type of encoding the string uses (if any) to get the size of it in bytes.

Comment: On second thought, sorry, but this is outright incorrect. `mb_strlen()` in conjunction with a multi-byte encoding is designed to return the size of the string in *characters*, not bytes. -1

Comment: Upon further investigation rather than simply reading stuff (which I will make a mental note to do more in future), you can still use mb_strlen() to get the desired result by either omitting the second parameter, or setting the second parameter to be 8bit.

Comment: @gabe yup, it's even the *only* bullet-proof way as per @ircmaxell's answer (I wasn't aware of that either).

Comment: Omitting the second parameters to MB_strlen wont work.  It will fallback on the default encoding then (UTF-8) and not return as expecting....

Comment: @ircmaxell I tried it and omitting the second parameter returned the same result as strlen did.  Maybe that's just the way I have my PHP set up though?  Just wondering.

Comment: It will return the same result for ASCII characters.  But if you have any UTF-8 characters in the string it won't return the correct result.  `mb_strlen` counts the number of characters in the string for the current character set.  The only way it'll return the number of bytes is to force the character set to a 1-byte-per-character charset.  And since some characters are not valid in the majority of the 1 byte character sets, `8-bit` is the only charset that will always return the correct byte length...