# How big is a string in PHP?

Tags: php

If I download a file from a website using:

```
$html = file_get_html($url);
```

Then how can I know the size, in kilobyes, of the HTML string? I want to know, because I want to skip files over 100Kb.

Comment: *"How long is a piece of string?"* :o)

Comment: You shouldn't retrieve the remote file THEN check for filesize. **You should use cURL** to find out the filesize before you download it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `file_get_contents`, you've already gotten the whole file.

If you mean "skip processing", rather than "skip retrieval", you can just get the length of the string: `strlen($html)`. For kilobytes, divide that by 1024.

This is imprecise because the string may contain UTF-8 characters over one byte in length, and very small files will actually occupy a FS block instead of their byte length, but it's probably good enough for the arbitrary-threshold cutoff you're looking for.

Comment: Depending on the character encoding, this may not be correct.

Comment: The OP is asking for the size in *bytes*, characters are irrelevant. FS blocks are irrelevant as well, since the string is not stored on disk at this point.

Comment: Out of interest, regarding the title of the question, do you know if there is a maximum size for a variable in PHP?  How many characters could $html store?

Comment: @deceze: it was stored somewhere, at some point, which is why I mentioned that on-disk representations are different from file contents. Re: MattP, I think PHP's limit is the available memory or 2^(address bits)-1. Very big, but of course this way of reading a file is terrible for non-trivially sized files anyhow...

Comment: Yes, it's nice to mention, but it has absolutely no relevance for transferring strings over HTTP. Very small strings will not grow because of FS block sizes in this context.

Comment: @Deceze: i'm retrieving web pages and i am trying to skip pages that are too big. this will do perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

To skip fetching large files, you want to use the [cURL library](http://php.net/curl).

```
<?php

function get_content_length($url) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
  $hraw=explode("\r\n",curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);

  $hdrs=array();
  foreach($hraw as $hdr) {
    $a=explode(": ", trim($hdr));
    $hdrs[$a[0]]=$a[1];
  }

  return (isset($hdrs['Content-Length'])) ? $hdrs['Content-Length'] : FALSE;
}

$url="http://www.example.com/";

if (get_content_length($url) < 100000) {
  $html = file_get_contents($url);
  print "Yes.\n";
} else {
  print "No.\n";
}

?>
```

There may be a more elegant way to pull this information out of curl, but this is what came to mind fastest.  YMMV.

Note that setting the CURLOPT options this way makes curl use a "HEAD" rather than "GET" request, so we're not actually fetching this URL twice.

Answer (score 2):

The definition, what a string is, is different between PHP and the intuitive meaning:

"Hällo" (mind the Umlaut) looks like a 5-character String, but to PHP it is really a 6-byte array (assuming UTF8) - PHP doesn't have a notion of a String representing text, it just sees it as a sequence of bytes (The PHP euphemism is "binary safe").

So strlen("Hällo") will be 6 (UTF8).

That said, if you want to skip above 100Kb you probably won't mind if it is 99.5k characters translating to 100k bytes.

Comment: The OP is asking about *bytes* anyway, where did he mention *characters*?

Comment: The OP may not have remembered that the two are not always the same.  Not everyone thinks that far ahead. That's why it's so great that we're all here to help.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mb_strlen to force 8bit or what not and then 1 character = 1 byte

Comment: OP is asking for *bytes* anyway, not characters.

Comment: You didn't read my statement, 1 byte =========== 1 character. Don't down vote stuff if you are not correct please.

Comment: Sorry, but "use mb_strlen to force latin1 or what not" is a nonsense statement. You probably mean "`mb_strlen` will give you an accurate *character count* even for multibyte encodings". That's not forcing latin1 or what not on the string nor is the OP asking about *characters* to begin with. At least correct the statement, I'll gladly remove the downvote then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511106/filesize-from-a-string read it. I'll change it from latin1 to 8bit to make you happy. In this case characters are equal to file size.

Comment: Read it. Nowhere does it say anything about latin1. And `mb_strlen($str, '8bit')` is equivalent to `strlen` anyway, which gives you a *byte count*. Why does everybody here insist on talking about characters when that was nowhere mentioned in the question?!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin1 Latin1 = 8-bit. And I don't understand what you don't get, characters are equal to size in this instance, 43 characters = 43 bytes.

Comment: Sure, but what if the page is encoded in UTF-8, and the OP is asking for the ***byte count***?! In UTF-8 1 character does not necessarily equal 1 byte. And nobody asked about character counts, only byte counts. And what's so special about latin1, there are many more 8bit character encodings than latin1!

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_html` returns an object to you, the information of how big the string is is lost at that point. Get the string first, the object later:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo strlen($html); // size in bytes
$html = str_get_html($html);
```